Hadran for Tanach?
Is there a hadran recitation to be said upon the completion of learning all of Tanach?

Here's one version:

הדרן עלך עשרים וארבעה ספרי התנ"ך דעתן עלך ודעתך עלן עשרים וארבעה ספרי התנ"ך. לא נתנשא מנך ולא תתנשא מנן לא בעלמא הדן ולא בעלמא דאתי.
ויהי רצון מלפניך ה' אלוקינו ואלקי אבותינו אשר בחר בנביאים טובים ורצה בדבריהם הנאמרים באמת שבזכות ספרי התנ"ך ממקראי קודש ובזכות פסוקיהם ותיבותיהם ואותיותיהם ונקודותיהם וטעמיהם ושמות הקדושים היוצאים מהם, ובזכות נביאי האמת, שופטי ישראל, וצדיקי הדורות המוזכרים בספרי התנ"ך נזכה להיות נועם ה' אלוקינו עלינו ומעשה ידינו כוננה עלינו ומעשה ידינו כוננהו, להיות זוכים היום ביום חתונתנו וביום שמחת לבנו. לעורר אם הבנים שמחה וליחד סוד תורה שבכתב עם סוד תורה שבעל פה ביחודא שלים באהבה ואחוה וריעות. הא-ל הנאמן בכל דבריו ימשיך עלינו שפע אור החיים לנפש, רוח ונשמה, להאריך ימינו בטוב וביראת ה' כל הימים. והערב נא ה' אלוקינו את דברי תורתך בפינו ובפי עמך בית ישראל, ונהיה אנחנו וצאצאינו וצאצאי צאצאינו וצאצאי עמך בית ישראל כולנו יודעי שמך ולומדי תורתך לשמה. ונשמח ונעלוז בדברי תלמוד תורתך ובמצותיך ובחוקותיך לעולם ועד. כי הם חיינו ואורך ימינו ובהם נהגה יומם ולילה. יהי ה' אלוקינו עמנו כאשר היה עם אבותינו, אל יעזבנו ואל יטשנו להיטיב לבבנו אליו, ללכת בכל דרכיו ולשמור מצותיו וחוקותיו ומשפטיו אשר צוה את אבותינו.
ויהי רצון מלפניך ה' אלקינו ואלקי אבותינו שכשם שעזרתנו לסיים עשרים וארבעה ספרי התנ"ך ממקראי קודש כן תעזרנו להמשיך ללמוד ספרים מתורה שבכתב ומתורה שבעל פה ולסיימם, ללמוד וללמד, לשמור לעשות ולקיים את כל דברי תלמוד תורתך באהבה. ותפתח לבבנו הערל בסודות תורתך הקדושה, ותאציל עלינו אור מקור נשמותינו בכל בחינותינו, ושיתנוצצו ניצוצי אבינו רועה משה רבנו ע"ה אשר על ידו גלית עמקי סודי תורתך. וזכותו וזכות כל נביאי ישראל הקדושים וספריהם וקדושתם יעמדו לנו שלא נכשל לעולם ועד, מתט אשורינו מתורתך הקדושה ח"ו, ולהיות דבריהם נאמנים ונחמדים, חיים וקיימים לעד ולעולמי עולמים עלינו ועל בנינו ועל דורותינו ועל כל דורות זרע ישראל עבדיך, על הראשונים ועל האחרונים דבר טוב וקיים באמת ובאמונה, חוק ולא יעבור. ונזכה ונחיה ונראה ונירש טובה וברכה לחיי העולם הבא. ובזכות התורה הקדושה שבכתב ושבע"פ הושיענו ה' אלוקינו וקבצנו מן הגוים, ומלוך על כל העולם כולו בכבודך והנשא על כל הארץ ביקרך. והשפיע עלינו אור ישועה ורחמים ממעייני הישועה.
אמן כן יהי רצון. יהיו לרצון אמרי פי והגיון לבי לפניך ה' צורי וגואלי.

